# Limit of Lebesgue integrals of sequence and convergence in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to develop a better understanding of convergence in $L^1$ .

Let $(X,M, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f_n, f \in L^1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Assume that for all measurable $A \subset X$ it is true that $\int_A f_n d\mu \xrightarrow{}\int_A f d\mu$, can we conclude that $\int_X|f-f_n| d\mu \xrightarrow{} 0$ (IOW $f_n \xrightarrow{L^1} f$)?

If not, I would appreciate (in addition to a counterexample) some explanation of the intuition as to why this does not hold.

For some reason, I have a feeling that this implication does not hold, but it seems that the case where $A = X$ proves the implication... am I missing something?

Comment: Since it's true for all measure sets, it's for $X$.

Comment: @MMM Just to clarify, are you saying that the last  line of my question, in fact, proves the overall implication?

Comment: if hypothesis is true for every subset of  $X$ (itself concluded) then it is obvious.

Comment: What if $f_n$ does not converge to $f$?

Comment: @Marios Gretsas Ok, and if we exclude X itself?

Comment: @Dondor then we have to think a little bit..;)

Comment: @d.k.o. What do you mean?  The assumption is that the convergence on each measurable $A$ holds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) provides a nice example.

Define $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ by $f_n(x) := \sin(2\pi n x)$ and define $f(x) := 0$.  Then
$$
\int_{[0,1]} \phi(x) f_n(x)\;dx \to 0
$$
for all $\phi \in L_1[0,1]$.  In particular, if $A \subseteq [0,1]$ is a measurable set, then
$$
\int_A f_n(x)\;dx \to 0 = \int_A f(x)\;dx
$$
But of course $\int_{[0,1]} |f_n-f|$ does not converge to $0$:
$$
\int_{[0,1]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\;dx = \int_0^1 |\sin(2\pi n x)|\;dx = 2n\int_0^{1/(2n)} \sin(2\pi n x)\;dx = \frac{2}{\pi}
$$

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!